# How to pass Authentication from ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de?

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [roboearth](http://ros.org/wiki/roboearth) doc.

I have already created an account sam.
I can login on [website](http://api.roboearth.org/login).

But I failed to login in terminal:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/cram$ svn info http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest
  Authentication realm: <http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de:80> RoboEarth Repository (BV)
  Password for 'sam': 
  Authentication realm: <http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de:80> RoboEarth Repository (BV)
  Username: sam
  Password for 'sam': 
  Authentication realm: <http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de:80> RoboEarth Repository (BV)
  Username: sam
  Password for 'sam': 
  svn: OPTIONS of 'http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de)
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/cram$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50058/how-to-pass-authentication-from-ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look closely, you'll notice that you are using http instead of http**s** in the URL. Try `$ svn info https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest`.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1